# Mifare classic 1K Reading/Writing implementation with ST25R3911B

Tags: authentication, cryptography, nfc, mifare

I'm completely new in the NFC field, I want to build an application by using Mifare classic 1K with ST25R3911B, For that purpose i have to make proper communication between them by which i can do communication between them(Like to read/write operation).
I'm getting success to read UID, but rest of the things i'm not understand like how to authenticate or which is the proper command by which i can do communication or shares information between them.
If anyone have experience or any knowledge regarding that please help me,
Any kind of help would be appreciated!
Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this chip, but I see its datasheet says that it supports Mifare as a custom protocol that you need to implement yourself as there is no generic method that is handled by the chip itself. That would mean you will need to implement the protocol based on NXP documentation including proprietary cryptography that is used there. If its only your private pet project, you could probably get away with some reverse engineered implementation that is floating around the internet, but the right way to do it is to contact NXP and obtain the license. Probably a way easier solution would be to replace the chip with something already licensed by NXP.

Comment: First of all thanks @Michal for your answer, I'm trying to implement protocol same as NXP and got only success upto first tag nonce!